# Does this sentence mean word count is 900-1200 including references and appendix?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, british-english, sentence

I usually get confused with the "plus" word.
The sentence:

> The suggested word limit for the document is between 900 and 1200 words (3 to 4 pages), plus the reference list and the appendix.

I was wondering if the word "plus" means *the word count is 900-1200 words*, but it includes the reference list and appendix in the word count?
So "plus" is more like "includes" word?

Comment: I can't think of any contexts where *plus* would mean *including*. Do you have any dictionary references that would support such an interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

The expected word count is *in addition* to the notes and carefully hand crafted excuses.

The problem is eternal. "$1.95 plus tax" made me wonder; does that include the tax? Turns out it does not. That is just the limit before the excess references and artisan verbiage is added.

Comment: "$1.95 plus tax" seems pretty unambiguous to me, the only thing that sort of labelling makes me wonder is why they don't make it easier for customers by just showing the total purchase price including tax (which is how we do it in Australia).

Comment: @KannE - That's an "interesting" system you've got there. While on holiday in America I went into a McDonald's, and they were advertising certain snacks on a "dollar menu" - none of the items could actually be purchased if all you had was one dollar, because tax was extra.

Comment: The comments are interesting. Never mind plus tax., How about plus votes?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a confusing way to write it. When you use "plus", it normally means "in addition to", so they're not included in the limit, but then it's strange to include them in the sentence stating the limit.

I think what they actually meant to say is that the suggested *length* of the document is 3-4 pages of main text, plus references and appendix. They just worded it poorly. A limit is also not usually stated as a "suggestion".